# Fill Down Formula (Set a Fromula & Copy Down AutoFill) Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet:

[image]

I am creating a script to add formulas on lines that are not empty, I got this result:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange('Odds Completas!O2').setFormula('=C2+J2');

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, 15, lr-1);
  ss.getRange('Odds Completas!O2').copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

The formula is defined in `O2`, but the others below are not. Instead, the following message appears:

**Number of rows in range must be at least 1. (row 6)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modification points:

- In your script, `ss` is declared by `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()`. On the other hand, the range uses the a1Notation including the sheet name. I think that the reason of your issue is this.

  - At `ss.getRange('Odds Completas!O2').setFormula('=C2+J2');`, the formula is put to the cell "O2" of the sheet `Odds Completas`.
  - At `var lr = ss.getLastRow();`, the last row of the active sheet is retrieved.
  - In this case, for example, if the active sheet is a new sheet, `lr` returns `0`. By this, the error occurs at `ss.getRange('Odds Completas!O2').copyTo(fillDownRange);`.

    - In your script, `lr-1` is used. So even when the last row is 1, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

### Modified script:

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is not modified. And before you run the script, please open the sheet of `Odds Completas` and run the script. By this, the script is run as the active sheet of `Odds Completas`, and `lr` returns the last row of `Odds Completas`.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your script is modified.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Odds Completas";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange('O2').setFormula('=Q2+J2');

  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(2, 15, lr-1);
  sheet.getRange('O2').copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

### References:

- [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet)

Comment: I have edited a detail in the question, please also edit the answer please, so that people researching the subject do not get confused. It was my fault ... Actually in ```fillDownRange``` the column must be ```15``` and not ```10``` as I had put it. Anyway, your answer was perfect, completely solved my need. Thank you very much

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And also thank you for additional information. I updated my answer.